# Overloading EFContextProvider AfterSaveEntities

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I am overloading AfterSaveEntities on my EFContextProvider and even though the entities are failing validation and not being stored in the database, the AfterSaveEntities method is still being called.

My question is "should AfterSaveEntities be called when nothing is actually saved because of a validation error?"

If AfterSaveEntities is supposed to be called in this way is there any way to tell at that point that the saveBundle was not actually saved?

Answer (score 0):

Do you overload or override the AfterSaveEntities method? I am guessing you overriding it and not overloading it. According to breezejs documentation "In AfterSaveEntities you have access to the entities after they've been saved successfully" http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/contextprovider.